# Getting shell output with Python?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a shell script that gets whois info for domains, and outputs `taken` or `available` to the shell depending on the domain.

I'd like to execute the script, and be able to read this value inside my Python script.

I've been playing around with `subprocess.call` but can't figure out how to get the output.

e.g.,

```
subprocess.call('myscript www.google.com', shell=True)
```

will output `taken` to the shell.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Some of the answers suggest using `subprocess.check_output`, which is new in 2.7.

Answer (score 8):

`subprocess.call()` does not give you the output, only the return code. For the output you should use `subprocess.check_output()` instead. These are friendly wrappers around the popen family of functions, which you could also use directly.

For more details, see: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 6):

Manually using stdin and stdout with Popen was such a common pattern that it has been abstracted into a very useful method in the subprocess module: [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['myscript', 'www.google.com'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = p.communicate(input="myinputstring")
# all done!
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen(["/usr/bin/svn", "update"], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, close_fds=True)
(stdout, stdin) = (p.stdout, p.stdin)
data = stdout.readline()
while data:
    # Do stuff with data, linewise.

    data = stdout.readline()
stdout.close()
stdin.close()
```

Is the idiom I use, obviously in this case I was updating an svn repository.

Answer (score 1):

try `subprocess.check_output`.